# How to concat all rows of a column of a data frame in pandas without group by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list, concatenation

Problem stmt -
Want to concat all rows of col and join with '|'

DataFrame -

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'body': 'Sahil', 'value': 'A123.456.234 '},
        {'body': 'Goyal', 'value': 'A124.457.235 '}
       ]
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

[image: dataframe]

Expected result -

[image: Expected_df]
**Facing issue when try to do it by aggregate fun -**

```
result = df.agg({"value": "|".join})
print(result)
print("\n")

# or

result = df['value'].apply(lambda x: "|".join(x))
print(result)
```

[image: response]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for pandas here, simply [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
out = '|'.join(df['value'].tolist())
```

Alternatively [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html), although this is less efficient:

```
out = df['value'].str.cat(sep='|')
```

Output: `'A123.456.234 |A124.457.235 '`

##### timings (on 200k rows)

```
%%timeit
'|'.join(df['value'].tolist())
# 2.46 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df['value'].str.cat(sep='|')
# 10.1 ms ± 446 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = '|'.join(df['value'].tolist())
print(result)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.